# aptitude says I'm running outdated binaries

Tags: linux, debian, kde, aptitude, kde-plasma-5

whenever I run

```bash
sudo apt install package-name
```

I get the following message at the end of the output:

> User sessions running outdated binaries:
> user @ session #2: plasmashell[1666]

this stays after rebooting

I'm running plasmashell 5.20.5 on debian 11 (as dual boot with windows 10).

How do I fix this?

thank you.

Comment: I think that's a bug with package `needrestart`. Try to uninstall it.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1404129/611902